# Facebook API send element_share payload?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm building a Node.js ChatBot with Wit.ai on Messenger and I just want to know if it's possible to track user action when they open The Share part on Messenger.

```
"recipient":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"generic",
        "elements":[
          {
            "title":"Breaking News: Record Thunderstorms",
            "subtitle":"The local area is due for record thunderstorms over the weekend.",
            "image_url":"https://thechangreport.com/img/lightning.png",
            "buttons":[
              {
                "type":"element_share"
              }              
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

There is no post back, no payload send to the ChatBot so How can I achieve this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is not a way in the Messenger api currently to detect users sharing an item.**

You could load the share url with parameters to identify the user, and listen for them on your server when loading the page. That could help attribute shares to users.

There is also the Messenger Extensions sdk which can [get the page scoped id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/userid) of a user on your site.